# Azure CosmosDB - update the property name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update the property name of the json in mongodb document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234556789"),
    "apps" : [
        {
            "_id" : 101,
            "regions" : [
                "WANAE",
                "WANAF"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 102,
            "regions" : [
                "WANAE",
                "WANAF"
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

in the above josn, I want to change apps `regions` to `codes`. Treid below queries but did not work

```
db.packs.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { 'apps.$.regions': 'apps.$.codes' } } );
db.packs.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { 'apps.$[].regions': 'apps.$[].codes' } } );
```

any help

***Update:*** As Joe suggested, I have a aggregation that changes the document with the changes needed and I tried updating the entire collection like below with the aggregated result

```
db.packs.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      apps: {
        $map: {
          input: "$apps",
          as: "app",
          in: {
            _id: "$$app._id",
            did: "$$app.did",
            name: "$$app.name",
            codes: "$$app.regions"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "apps.regions":0
    }
  },
  {
    $out:"packs"
  }
])
```

As per the documentation, `$out` should replace the existing collection if it is exists but I received an error that says I have to supply a new collection name `Please supply a collection that does not already exist to the $out stage.`. Isn't `$Out` replace the exiting `packs` with new aggregated results

Comment: What is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: We are using azure cosmos DB and it says `server version 3.2`

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a field in an array of objects, like "$apps.regions", the value is an array containing all of the values of that field from all of the elements.

If you set the value of regions directly, each sub document will contain an array of arrays, probably not what you want.

renaming the field in the entire array of objects will require iterating the array, perhaps with $map or $reduce.

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can do that with a pipeline in an update:

```
db.packs.updateMany( {}, [
 {$set: {
      "apps": {
        $map: {
          input: "$apps",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                codes: "$$this.regions"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$unset: "apps.regions"}
]}
```

If you are using an earlier version, you'll need to do that with aggregation, perhaps with `$out`, and then replace the original collection with the updated one.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this and got `2020-05-14T18:33:34.208-0400 E QUERY    [js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1`. How to look for mongodb version when it is from azure. I see it has server version as 3.2

Comment: And I am pretty new to mongdb so unsure about usage of `$out`. Appreciate your help

Comment: that error suggest you are running MongoDB 3.6.  Try running those in an aggregation pipeline with the addition of a stage like `{$out: "newcollectionname"}`

Comment: I am using Studio 3T(Robo 3T) tool to execute the query. In aggregate pipeline I see $out as a filter but I do not see $set and $unset. Sorry for my limited knowledge

Comment: `$set` is an alias for `$addFields` and `{$unset: "apps.regions"}` is equivalent to `{$project:{"apps.regions":0}}`

Comment: @arjun : When it comes to CosmosDB, I guess the latest version of Cosmos DB is only compatible with MongoDB's version of 3.6. So I guess 3.2 is mostly similar to 3.2 & from my past experience cosmosDB doesn't support all the operators that are supported by MongoDB, I believe `$map` is not supported & also please be cautious about `$out` as it's destructive cause it will drop entire collection & re-create with result of aggregation pipeline so you really need to test your aggregation well prior to using `$out` as last stage..